# focus in textbox not going after alert in FF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am doing length validation with java script. If input is short in length I shows an alert and after that I want to set focus back in the text field. It is working in IE but not working in FF. I have searched a lot on google but no solution could work plz guide and help me.

```
function IsLengthOK(_title,_control,_length)
        {
               if(_control.value.length < _length)
                {   
                   alert("'"+ _title +"'" + " must be minimum "+_length+"  characters in length");                                                                                            
                   document.getElementById('txtUserName').focus();

                   return(false);  
                }
        }
```

I am calling this function here on textbox's blur event:

```
if(IsLengthOK("Registration Username",this,6))
        {
       // do something next.            
        }
```

HTML of my textbox is:

```
<input id="txtUserName" type="text" tabindex="1" name="txtUserName" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% white;">
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  Specifically, txtUserName

Comment: @user576510, please stop using "plz."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function IsLengthOK(_title,_control,_length) {
  if(_control.value.length < _length) {   
    alert("'" + _title + "'" + " must be minimum " + _length + " characters in length");
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('txtUserName').focus();
    }, 0);
    return false;
  }
}
```

This's working in my Firefox. It will have the focus on object#txtUserName after the `setTimeout` called.

Comment: @Ronak, I tried it but as I clicked on ok in alert box, focus goes to a image on top banner in the page. Is there any thing to do with tab order etc ?

Comment: You won't have access to `ele` in your `setTimeout` because you passed the function in a string which will be `eval()`'d in a different context.

Comment: @Ronak Why introduce a global when you could just create an anonymous function there?

Comment: @alex Why create an anonymous function when you can use an element with one global variable?

Comment: @Ronak Because you have a nice encapsulated function that has a variable that is needlessly global.

Comment: @alex ok, you can change that global variable code with this line: `setTimeout("document.getElementById('txtUserName').focus();", 0);` is this fine with you, @alex?

Comment: @Ronak Didn't mean to come across as anything but helpful :) and yes that will work, though I'd still consider it less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me in Firefox 4.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/XMcLj/).

Here is a suggested rewrite of your function...

```
function IsLengthOK(_title, _control, _length) {
    if (_control.value.length < _length) {
        alert("'" + _title + "'" + " must be minimum " + _length + "  characters in length");
        _control.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/XMcLj/1/).

- You are passing a reference to your element but then selecting it again. There is no reason to do that. It will only make maintenance more difficult. It will also bind that function to your one element when it could easily be more flexible.
- You return `false` in parenthesis. That is not necessary. Also, if the condition is true, it returns `false`, so it would stand to reason otherwise it should return `true` (instead of `undefined`).
- If you have a bunch of validation utility functions like this, it may be a good idea to namespace them as methods of a `Validator` object, for example.
- Why do you prefix your variables with `_`? You should drop them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `document.getElementById`, like you are here:

```
document.getElementById('txtUserName').focus();
```

Use a jquery selector and then extract the raw element, like so.

```
$('#txtUserName')[0].focus();
```

Comment: same result. as I pressed ok button in alert box focus goes to a image in banner.